# How to update profile (displayName) firebase in React Native?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I found a problem to update profile firebase in React Native, I try to look for example but fails all, maybe you can give me advices or you can correct my script.

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
    .then(
      (user)=>{
        if(user){
          user.updateProfile({
            displayName: 'Frank S. Andrew'
          }).then((s)=> {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Account');
          })
        }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      alert(error.message);
    });
```

I try to follow all examples, in the alert shows message 'user.updateProfile is not a function'.

Please anyone help me how to update profile (displayName) firebase in React Native.

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [`createUserWithEmailAndPassword` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createUserWithEmailAndPassword) returns a [`UserCredential` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#.UserCredential). This is not a `User` itself, but **has** a `user` property, which is a [`User` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User).

So what you need it:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
    .then((userCredentials)=>{
        if(userCredentials.user){
          userCredentials.user.updateProfile({
            displayName: 'Frank S. Andrew'
          }).then((s)=> {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Account');
          })
        }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      alert(error.message);
    });
```